# Artinian quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is an artinian ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then is the quotient ring $R/I$ artinian?

If its not can someone provide examples?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have an infinite chain $(J_1 + I) \geq (J_2 + I) \geq (J_3 + I) \geq \ldots$ in $R/I$, then using that the sum of ideals is again an ideal, we get that $(J_1 + I) \geq (J_2 + I) \geq (J_3 + I) \geq \ldots$ is an infinite chain in $R$ and thus a contradiction to $R$ being artinian.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $R$ is an Artinian ring with ideal $I$. Then $R/I$ is also an Artinian ring as follows:

Consider any descending chain of ideals in $R/I$: $$J_1+I\supseteq J_2+I\subseteq\cdots$$ Then $J_1\supseteq J_2\supseteq\cdots$ forms a descending chain of ideals in Artinian ring $R$ and so it must terminate i.e., $J_k=J_{k+1}=\cdots$ for some $k$ and so $J_k+I=J_{k+1}+I=\cdots$ as well, that is the descending chain $J_1+I\supseteq J_2+I\subseteq\cdots$ also terminates and hence $R/I$  is an Artinian ring.